# What are my choices for transforming data that are not normally distributed?

Tags: r, matlab, data-transformation

I have two sets of data comparing two variables: x and y. I'd like to transform and compare both sets either in `r` or `matlab`.

**Scatter plot**

[image]

Neither are normal and come from (by the looks of it) different distributions)

**QQPLOT of data 1**

[image]

**QQPLOT of data 2**

[image]

I would like to transform both data sets to compare them on a level playing field but I know they are not normally distributed, though I don't know from what distribution they come. What are my choices?

Comment: What is the end goal here? i.e. How exactly do you plan to compare them?

Comment: Data 1 are experimental. Data two come from a model which had to estimate some parameters. My end goal is to show that after some sort of transformation they are statistically significantly similar (ie that somehow they are a scaled version of each other, or some such). I will use the Kuskall-Wallis test here after the transformation. But what are my best choices to make such a transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why transform at all?  If you use a nonparametric test, normality is not assumed.

2) "Statistically significantly similar" is tricky; usually statistical significance applies to a difference (although there are also equivalence tests).

3) I am not sure what your first plot does... what are the two axes?

4) Are your QQPLOTs plots against a normal distribution? It looks like data 1 is truncated

EDIT in response to comments:
You do seem to want some kind of regression here. I would first look at a scatterplot of the two variables. Then I'd try an ordinary least square regression for starters, and look at the residuals. If there are problems with normality and homoscedasticity, you might need to do something else.

By the way, I still am not sure what that first plot is.

Comment: Let me put it into perspective: the experimental data are the bacteria colonies (y) on nurses' hands after time (x) 1)The reason for transformation was because the data1 are experimental but data2 are predicted. Although the mechanics of accruing germs is known, the quantity on surfaces they touched is not. So surely I need a transformation to make them comparable?

Comment: QQPLOTS were against normal distributions. And data 1 is truncated because detectability of germs has an upper limit.

Comment: Why would the fact that one is actual data and the other is predicted mean that you need a transformation?  It might mean that what you want regression, rather than Kruskal Wallis. That is, the DV would be actual germs and the IV predicted germs

Comment: Ah interesting, I see that using regression wouldn't need any transformation. Are we talking general linear modelling or something else would you say? Also what do you think about that truncated data?

Comment: Just try out some GLM first, as @PeterFlom has suggested.